# Is there any length limit of string stored in Keychain?

Tags: iphone, ios, keychain

I want to store some userinfo as a string in Keychain on iOS, so is there any length limit of the string in Keychain?

Thanks.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I threw together an iOS app that would do a binary search using [this library](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/UICKeyChainStore) to interact with the keychain, and determined that the most I could store was an NS(Mutable)String with length 16,777,110. So noticeably less than either the max length of an NSString or the default value of SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH as suggested in other answers.

EDIT: If you're looking to quickly verify this answer, I'd suggest trying to store a String with length 16,777,110 in the keychain, and then trying one with length 16,777,111. If the first one works and the second one doesn't, this answer is correct.

Comment: And what about performance ? How long does it take to store / get a long String from the Keychain ?

Comment: Btw, 16777110 bytes ~= 16 MB

Answer (score 17):

It's hard to answer :) It should support the maximum length of [NSString](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Fdocumentation%2FCocoa%2FReference%2FFoundation%2FClasses%2FNSString_Class%2F&ei=RjNKVY7TB4LT7QbQ2oGYDw&usg=AFQjCNHcA5tu5wwE2Gg5Ms0OoEEDWSdRNg&bvm=bv.92291466,d.ZGU)

So the Keychain string can hold a little over **4.2 billion** characters same as [NSString](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Fdocumentation%2FCocoa%2FReference%2FFoundation%2FClasses%2FNSString_Class%2F&ei=RjNKVY7TB4LT7QbQ2oGYDw&usg=AFQjCNHcA5tu5wwE2Gg5Ms0OoEEDWSdRNg&bvm=bv.92291466,d.ZGU)

Comment: That's a pretty big keychain

Comment: According to [Mark's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24165635/199364), testing this experimentally yields a much lower limit.

Answer (score 6):

The keychain of iOS is realized as SQLite-database (see [here](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/iphone-penetration-testing-3/) for example). So the max length of a string stored in an SQLite-database could be an upper bound for the max length for a string in the keychain.

According to [this page](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) on *sqlite.org* the max number of bytes for a string or BLOB is limited by the preprocessor macro *SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH*, whose default-value is *10^9*. So assuming a 16-bit-encoding of the string, the max length of a string would be the half of this value. However, it could be that Apple uses a lower value for *SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH*.