# Share data across multiple apps on iOS

Tags: ios, data-storage

I know there are quite a few threads on this, but it seems none of them would satisfy what I am trying to look for. Here's my constraints:

- not a hack that uses private API/framework or undocumented
  directory access that would run the risk of app being rejected
  because of that
- being able to share data across different
  vendors / app developers
- data can persist outside the lifecycle
  of the app (even after app is deleted)

UPDATED: I was in general trying to stay away from using a 3rd party cloud-based service to achieve the goal as this would introduce additional external dependency. But if I have to, I was hoping it could satisfy this one constraint

- being able to tell which iOS device it is communicating with. It shouldn't have to uniquely identify the device (which will go into that evil UDID discussion route as we all experienced ). But as long as it can differentiate among different iOS devices it should be fine.

Comment: Have you considered a common cloud service for hosting the data?

Comment: Have you checked PasteBoard API on ios SDK? Here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference

Comment: @AgungPratama As of iOS 7, apps can only share a common (named) pasteboard if the apps are from the same developer.

Comment: PasteBoard cannot reliably persist and user can interfere and override the pasteboard content

Comment: UIPasteboard would have worked prior to iOS 7. You could have created a named pasteboard that any app could access, to read and write data that way. I was going to do that this way, out of desperation, because I wanted local data. I figured something like this would happen after talking to an Apple developer at WWDC this year.

But like rmaddy said, they altered the API so that only common vendor id apps can view a named pasteboard. (I sure hope I didn't give them the idea of locking this down)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [this blog post](http://smilesoftware.com/blog/entry/how-ios-7-affects-textexpander-touch) by TextExpander authors will help:

> Smile has responded to this by discussing the issue with Apple
>   engineers at WWDC, filing a bug (#14168862), and checking up on the
>   status of that bug. We also developed a workaround by storing the
>   TextExpander data in a new place. Reminders requires user consent to
>   store and retrieve data. Completed reminders are not normally shown in
>   its interface. Long-past reminders appear at the bottom of the
>   completed reminders.
>
> TextExpander touch 2.1 (and later) supports storing shared snippet
>   data in a long-past, completed reminder. We produced an updated SDK
>   and kept our developers posted on its progress. Our final SDK was
>   ready within a few hours of the end of Apple's official iOS 7
>   announcement.

**UPDATE (22.11.2013)**
This might not be the best way to do that, because TextExpander's team [recently had problems with the App Review Team](http://www.macstories.net/linked/textexpander-touch-to-be-revised-significantly-following-apple-rejection/).

Comment: thanks, Arkadiusz. this seems to be the best solution for me.

Answer (score 4):

I kind of need this too. I use Parse.com as the backend of all my apps — their free tier should satisfy your development needs.

Parse has APIs available for iOS, Android, Windows 8, OS X, JavaScript and .NET, with all your data available on the cloud on any platform (contrary to Core Data and iCloud). They also offer "Cloud Code," which is code you can execute remotely, to process information remotely and get the data back to your app.

You should definitely [check Parse.com](http://parse.com) out for cloud storage for your app. In my experience, it really gets the job done.

For Data Persistence, I think you might want to take a look at [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) (although if you decide to persist data locally, it will get deleted with your app, but it might help you, anyways). Core Data is an overkill in many cases.

**Edit:** Parse.com has an "Installation" class, in which all the devices that have your app installed get listed (wether they're running iOS or Android), uniquely, without you having to type any code.

Comment: +1 For Parse. Their documentation (at least for iOS) is great and it's super easy to use. The fact that it works seamlessly across platforms is a bonus as well, considering it's all just JSON objects for the most part.

Comment: Parse is amazing and definitely reliable and easy to use considering it is owned by Facebook. I have used it in some web apps recently, it has decent query functions as well that help sort data which comes in very handy.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit: this only works for apps with the same vendor.**

You can save a password to the device's keychain, then access that password from any app.

Using the [SSKeychain](https://github.com/soffes/sskeychain) library...

```
NSString *service = @"com.yourcompany.yourservice";

// read
NSString *password = [SSKeychain passwordForService:service account:@"user"];

// write
[SSKeychain setPassword:password forService:service account:@"user"];
```

The password string [doesn't have a length limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488793/is-there-any-length-limit-of-string-stored-in-keychain), so encode all your data as a string and save it there.  The keychain entry will persist after the user deletes the app.

Comment: thanks Neal. to share data via keychain, two app has to use the same app id / bundle seed id prefix, so data cannot be shared across apps from different developer/vendors.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to do this is using THRIFT.  This is a data communication protocol that would need a back end server (private) and THRIFT can be compiled into many languages / platforms.  There is a meta language to describe the data and then can be thrift compiled into many languages.  Write the data definition once and can be used on many platforms.

More information at.

http://thrift.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

for me (I have 2 apps and a widged) the best solution is using [SSKeyChain](https://github.com/soffes/SAMKeychain) and do not forget to add `Capabilities` for your apps like [here](http://evgenii.com/blog/sharing-keychain-in-ios/)

or if you don't wanna to use 3rd party library you can use `NSUserDefaults` and set the group identifier like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24063144/2050181) but again do not forget to add the group identifier in `Capabilities` in [AppGroups](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH26-SW61) section for all your apps that have share data.