# NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults not working with extension

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, ios8

I added App Groups to my app ID in the developer portal and am using that App ID in my provisioning profile. My Product Identifier in Xcode is set to that app ID.

In my app delegate I call this from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("hey", forKey: "TEST")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

In my keyboard app extension I call this:

```
if let test = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("TEST") as? String
 {
    println(test)
 }
```

This never is true. If I remove the validation test and just print the result the custom keyboard crashes.

EDIT
Have also tried this with same crash result:

App Delegate

```
var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.jackedgames.myappgroup")
userDefaults.setObject("TEST", forKey: "TEST")
userDefaults.synchronize()
```

Keyboard Extension

```
var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.jackedgames.myappgroup")
var test = userDefaults.objectForKey("TEST") as String
NSLog(test)
```

In the "Capabilities" section of both targets I have the groups enabled with this group ID selected.

What am I missing here?

Comment: did you call `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()`?

Comment: Yes. But i'm pretty sure that synchronize() is an optional call anyway

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24064722/save-and-load-data-on-today-extensions-ios-8

Comment: `synchronize()` is *usually* optional...

Comment: This really probably shouldn't be marked as a duplicate of an Objective-C question.

Comment: @nhgrif This is a Cocoa Touch, iOS 8 question independent of language. The same exact thing can be written in ObjC

Comment: It sort of can, yes... but as someone who knows Objective-C and hasn't spent a ton of time with Swift yet, I can't see what's wrong with this, and as such I assume it's something specific to Swift syntax.  And if it is a problem with the Swift syntax, then again... it really shouldn't be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @nhgrif I agree and understand what you are saying. It doesn't apply here though. The solution is to use new API introduced in iOS 8 (`initWithSuiteName`) with App Groups and has nothing to do with syntax.

Comment: Oh, I see now.  I didn't look at the answers to that question.

Comment: Unfortunately the solutions on that question do not work. I am wondering if NSUserDefaults is not working on Keyboard extensions yet

Answer (score 1):

1. Set

   ```
   RequestsOpenAccess = YES;
   ```
2. Settings:

   ```
   NSUserDefaults * usrInfo = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"myKeyboard"];

   [usrInfo setObject:theme.icon forKey:@"themeName"];  // This is the new data;

   [usrInfo synchronize];
   ```
3. keyboardChange:

   ```
   NSUserDefaults * usrInfo = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"myKeyboard"];

   [usrInfo synchronize];

    NSString * str = [usrInfo objectForKey:@"themeName"];
   ```

Then you can change the keyboard , for example ,change its background

Comment: Thanks, man. I have seen so many people sharing the code and missing the important step to add RequestsOpenAccess in info.plist.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your keyboard from the iOS settings menu and add it again with "allow full access permission". It should work.

If it still doesn't work, check for both  containing application and keyboard extension in target configuration in "Capabilities" section in app group that there are everything is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Just stepped on this. In keyboard extension you need "Full Access" to have access to write something to the app group files. So without "Full Access" you need to use `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults`

The problem is that when you're changing NSUserDefaults from app group - it is working until you restart the app, because it stores values in memory too. Hard to debug.

I'm saving value to both: app group `NSUserDefaults` and `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults`. And when reading - checking both too.