# Create a Containing app for ios 8 keyboard with multiple colors

Tags: ios8, custom-keyboard

Currently I have many different XCode projects that are each the same custom ios8 keyboard and the only difference between them is that they each are a different color. The question that I have is how would I combine these keyboards into a single container app that would allow you to switch keyboard colors through the app? 
Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSUserdefaults, app groups and allow full access.

Check: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25784582/840742

Note, your app extension and container app must be in same app group (capabilities tab of target settings page in Xcode).