# In Swift, how would I pass a permanent variable from the main iOS app to an extension (e.g. today extension, custom keyboard)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

For the main app, I can permanently store a key by using `UserDefaults.standard`

in `appDelegate` I have:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let defaultValue = ["userUID" : ""]
defaults.register(defaults: defaultValue)
```

then, when user registers I have:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(user!.uid, forKey: "userUID")
defaults.synchronize()
```

and when I want to read it, it's perfect. However, I'm not exactly sure how to pass this "userUID" upon registration to the custom keyboard extension, and permanently save it there.

I know I can pass data using app groups, and having:

```
let defaultsToKeyboard = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "group.com.app")
```

but this gets erased on every new instantation. Looking for a swift 3 solution.

Comment: Is the data you wish to store really confidential? If it is, you should look into [keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html), which is a lot more secure and the data can be shared between your apps.

Comment: It's not confidential, but if keychain is an easy alternative I can consider it. It's just hard to believe that there is a UserDefaults.standard, which perma stores data until app is deleted, but you can't pass this perma data to an extension.

Comment: I think I'm also not fully understanding the "init(suieName)" data passing, because it seems the main app has to be open and those lines have to run for data to pass, but then when keyboard opens later, how does it read it? Is it stored somewhere as an instance, and once custom keyboard launches that data is then passed, or permanently stored? No appDelegate for extensions which makes things tricky.

Comment: Yes, so maybe you should use keychain

Comment: I would prefer to learn and fully understand the process than to jump to another solution. It is working right now, so something tells me the init suiteName might be permanent, however haven't extensively tested, and would love an answer that explains in detail the communication that is occurring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to set and read `UserDefaults` between two apps:

1. Select your project in the project navigator
2. Select the main app target and go to the capabilities tab
3. Turn on "App groups"
4. Create a new container that starts with “group.”, so give it a name like “group.foo.bar”.
5. Select your Keyboard Extension target and switch on app groups again. Don’t create a new container, rather select the created container (group.foo.bar) to signify that the Keyboard Extension is a member of the container.

This is how you write to the `UserDefaults`:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.foo.bar") //replace suiteName with your container name
let defaultValue = ["userUID" : ""]
defaults!.register(defaults: defaultValue)
defaults!.set("a", forKey: "userUID")
defaults!.synchronize()
```

And how to read from the keyboard extension:

```
let defaultsToKeyboard = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.foo.bar") //replace suiteName with your container name
let uid = defaultsToKeyboard?.object(forKey: "userUID")
print("\(uid)")
```

Basically this allows apps that is part of the group to access the same `UserDefaults`. `UserDefaults` are not destroyed even after the containing app is deleted. `UserDefaults` are always saved to disk, so it will never be destroyed. When you use app sharing, your apps inside the group are actually accessing **the same `UserDefaults`**. That's why there is a `synchronize` function, it saves the `UserDefaults` to disk and also why it is unsafe, anybody who can see the underlying file system can look at its contents.

Your extension can also 'see' the `UserDefaults`. It just can't access it. Creating group ids tells iOS that your extension (or even app) is authorized to access it, so it can read and write data to and from it.

Your app is not needed to be in the foreground to access the `UserDefaults` as it is saved on disk already!

**Remember that `UserDefaults` are saved to disk and not stored in an instance!**

Comment: This applies to all different types of UserDefaults? both standard and innit(suiteName:String)? This is a really excellent answer by the way. I already had this working, but it clarifies some confusion.

Comment: the only difference I have is UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "group.com.foo")

Comment: Yes, all UserDefaults are written to disk

Comment: How would I save permanent variables that only need to be seen in the custom extension? For the main app when I did it, I used the main appDelegate, but since extension doesn't have mainApp, I guess I can do this same way?

Comment: The OS invokes `widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler:` when the extension is loaded. Use a group id (eg group.foo.bar) to save it, or create a new group id just for the extension see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24064722/save-and-load-data-on-today-extensions-ios-8) for more details.

Comment: where is this invoked? is this an override of a method? I guess I can do NSUSERDEFAULTS in viewDidLoad, but I'm worried it would continuously set the initial value to whatever I originally set it to.

Comment: I created a new group in my extension, and made a function that I ran in viewDidLoad, then later read the data. if function runs it works fine, but if I comment function out (after running it the time before), and then try to get data, I get nil. So I guess I can't do this in viewDidLoad?

Comment: `widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler` is part of `NCProvidingControl`, see here for [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/notificationcenter/ncwidgetproviding). Conform to it and override it. It gives opportunities to let the OS update the widget.