# ios8 extension and container app how to share data

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-app-extension

I'm having trouble to share data between iOS 8 extension and container app. 
I set up the group from develop portal and Xcode, and my entitlements plist both look like:

```
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>my group id</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

The suggested solution in apple document to use `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`

doesn't work for me.

I've tried the solution by @Santa Claus from this post [Communicating and persisting data between apps with App Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24015506/communicating-between-apps-with-app-groups/24066826#24066826) to use

```
[[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"<group identifier>"];
```

Santa Claus's solution worked on simulator but not on my iPhone 4s, any ideas on how to make it work on real device? Or am I missing anything?

Some updates:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group id"];
```

function returns url, and both urls from container app and extension look the same, as "*path /private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/3DFB9750-A9F3-4C37-BC3C-0D5BF746B‌​233"*.
I created a json file inside that folder from container app but extension can't find any file in the folder when I run on device. But in simulator it finds it well and everything works.

Comment: I can confirm [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24063144/2446155) works on devices as well. Try uninstalling your applications and re-install them.

Comment: Thanks, I tried uninstalling, it still doesn't work on device..

Comment: Confirm your group id is typed exactly the same in both application entitlements and in the `NSUserDefaults` initialization

Comment: They are all the same, no luck :(

Comment: See if [the other solution to that question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24028248/2446155) works. You don't have to use it, but it will reveal whether app groups are setup correctly.

Comment: I tried to use  NSURL *containerURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] 
           containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group id"], i could get a valid NSURL from container app but, from the extension it always returns nil. Could you get same NSURL from app and extension? Maybe my group is not set up correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55198/discussion-between-santa-claus-and-woof).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Communicating between apps with App Groups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24015506/communicating-between-apps-with-app-groups)

Comment: Did anyone ever find a guaranteed solution for getting this to work on an device?

Comment: I am also facing this issue , I have some images in host app and trying to access in child(extension) app getting valid url but sometimes it fetch the image sometimes its not . please update if some one have paramagnet fix.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

My solution is edit the Info.plist of my custom keyboard:

NSExtension -> NSExtensionAttributes -> RequestsOpenAccess

Make it YES.

Then delete the keyboard in your device and re-add it. In your keyboard add page you will find a setting named "Allow Full Access", enable it and the keyboard will access the shared data.

Comment: working in simulator but same thing not working in device any idea why?

Comment: nice!! it took me so long to find what it wasn't working... would you know of a way to detect the setting value from the extension?

Comment: @heheBear this works for me on Simulator but not on real device any suggestion ?

Comment: in my case (Sharing extension) is not working, i have added it in plist but not show on real device ,only work on simulators

Answer (score 2):

For keyboard extension, make sure enable RequestsOpenAccess as heheBear's answer
and try remove and add back keyboard from Setting/Keyoboard occasionally
keyboard extension is not stable and performance is really bad since beta 4, include beta 5

Answer (score 1):

The problem only occurs for custom keyboard, and iOS8 beta 2 fixed the issue.

Comment: iOS 8 beta 5 still does not work on real device, only on simulator

Comment: Looks like iOS GM sill having this issue, working on simulators but no device!