# Sharing data between an iOS 8 share extension and main app

Tags: ios, swift, ios-app-extension, userdefaults

Recently, I've been making a simple iOS 8 share extension to understand how the system works. As Apple states in its [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW1):

> By default, your containing app and its extensions have no direct access to each other’s containers.

Which means the extension and the containing app do not share data. But in the same page Apple brings a solution:

> If you want your containing app and its extensions to be able to share data, use Xcode or the Developer portal to enable app groups for the app and its extensions. Next, register the app group in the portal and specify the app group to use in the containing app.

Then it becomes possible to use NSUserDefaults to share data between the containing app and the extension. This is exactly what I would like to do. But for some reason, it does not work.

In the same page, Apple suggests the standard defaults:

```
var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
```

In a WWDC presentation (217), they suggest a common package:

```
var defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: kDefaultsPackage)
```

Also, I enabled App Groups for both the containing app target and the extension target, with the same App Group name:
[image: XCode Target capabilities, App Groups]

But all this setup is for nothing. I cannot retrieve the data I stored in the containing app, from the extension. It is like two targets are using completely different NSUserDefaults storages.

So,

1. Is there a solution for this method?
2. How can I share simple data between the containing app and the share extension? The data is just user credentials for an API.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Communicating between apps with App Groups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24015506/communicating-between-apps-with-app-groups)

Comment: This may help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/24015506/1586692

But I still have problem like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/24067975/1586692

Answer (score 50):

You should use NSUserDefaults like this:

**Save data:**

objc

```
NSUserDefaults *shared = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.yougroup"];
[shared setObject:object forKey:@"yourkey"];
[shared synchronize];
```

swift

```
let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.yourgroup")
defaults?.set(5.9, forKey: "yourKey")
```

**Read data:**

objc

```
NSUserDefaults *shared = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.yougroup"];
id value = [shared valueForKey:@"yourkey"];
NSLog(@"%@",value);
```

swift

```
let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.yourgroup")
let x = defaults?.double(forKey: "yourKey")
print(x)
```

This will work fine!

Comment: swift language was asked please update your post using or at least adding swift language

Comment: Its nice to see objective c along side swift. It helps understand the difference. Considering theres tonns of code examples of ObjC and not many of swift at the moment its good to understand how to convert it.

Comment: Actually in Swift the .synchronize() is redundant

Answer (score 15):

Here is how I did it:

1. Open your main app target > Capabilities > App Groups set to on
2. Add a new app group and make sure it is ticked (e.g. group.com.seligmanventures.LightAlarmFree)
3. Open your watch target (the one with Capabilities tab) > App Groups set to on
4. Add a new app group and make sure it is ticked (e.g. group.com.seligmanventures.LightAlarmFree - but must be the same name as group above)
5. Save data to the group as follows:

   ```
   var defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.seligmanventures.LightAlarmFree")
   defaults?.setObject("It worked!", forKey: "alarmTime")
   defaults?.synchronize()
   ```
6. Retrieve data from the group as follows:

   ```
   var defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.seligmanventures.LightAlarmFree") 
   defaults?.synchronize()

   // Check for null value before setting
   if let restoredValue = defaults!.stringForKey("alarmTime") {
       myLabel.setText(restoredValue)
   }
   else {
       myLabel.setText("Cannot find value")
   }
   ```

Comment: Do you know if defaults.suiteName are permanently stored, just like defaults.standard?

Comment: Syntax update
var defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.seligman")
defaults?.set(sharedTxt, forKey: "shared")

Answer (score 7):

If you have

```
group.yourappgroup
```

use

```
var defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "yourappgroup")
```

This works for me

Comment: i get the error Incorrect argument label in call (have 'suiteName:', expected 'user:')

Comment: Right, neither this does work for me. Xcode 6 shows the appropriate exception: `Using your own bundle identifier as an NSUserDefaults suite name does not make sense and will not work. Break on _NSUserDefaults_Log_Nonsensical_Suites to find this`. With the prefix `group.` though it works.

Comment: @naturalc NSUserDefaults(suiteName:) returns an optional NSUserDefaults. You should use optional binding to make sure it's valid. Try putting the ! at the end.

Comment: @Pops: That's a bug in the Swift annotations for `NSUserDefaults`. Actually the argument should be optional, not the init itself. I have already reported it.

Answer (score 5):

So apparently it works, only when the **group name** is used as the **suite name** for NSUserDefaults.

The documentation says NSUserDefaults.standartUserDefaults() should also work but it does not, and this is probably a bug.

Comment: Can you add some sample code of setting up the `NSUserDefaults` and the passing of the data. Thanks

Comment: Do you have to add the group to both targets?

Comment: I believe UserDefaults.standard uses the bundle identifier under the hood. Since your main app and extension will have different bundle IDs, the standard user defaults will not work.

Answer (score 3):

In my scenario I'm sharing data between the parent iOS app and WatchKit. I'm using Xcode 6.3.1, iOS Deployment Target 8.3

```
var defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.yourappgroup.example")
```

In your viewDidLoad make sure you synchronize:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    defaults?.synchronize()

}
```

Example of a button sending text but of course you can pass whatever:

```
 @IBAction func btnSend(sender: UIButton) {
    var aNumber : Int = 0;
    aNumber = aNumber + 1

    //Pass anything with this line
    defaults?.setObject("\(aNumber)", forKey: "userKey")
    defaults?.synchronize()

}
```

Then on the other side make sure app group matches:

```
 var defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.yourappgroup.example")
```

Then synchronize and cal: (In this case "lblNumber" is an IBOutlet label)

```
defaults?.synchronize()
var tempVar = defaults!.stringForKey("userKey")!;
lblNumber.setText(tempVar);
```

Then if you wanted to set something on this side and sync it back then just do the same thing and synchronize and just make sure the stringForKey that you call on the other side is the same:

```
defaults?.setObject("sending sample text", forKey: "sampleKey")
defaults?.synchronize()
```

Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 2):

I translated in swift foogry's answer and it works!!

Save data:

```
let shared = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "nameOfCreatedGroup")
shared("Saved String 1", forKey: "Key1")
shared("Saved String 2", forKey: "Key2")
```

Read data:

```
let shared = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "nameOfCreatedGroup")!
valueToRead1 = shared("Key1") as? String
valueToRead2 = shared("Key2") as? String
println(valueToRead1)   // Saved String 1
println(valueToRead2)   // Saved String 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You may share data by Following below steps:

1) Select your project -> Select Capabilities tab -> Enable App Groups -> Click on '+' -> paste your bundle Id after 'group.'

[image: Enable AppGroups in project capabilities tab]

2) Select your Extension -> Select Capabilities tab -> Enable App Groups -> Click on '+' -> paste your bundle Id after 'group.'

[image: Enable AppGroups in Extension capabilities tab]

3) Place below code in your main app for which data you want to share:

```
NSUserDefaults * appGroupData = [[NSUserDefaults alloc]initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.appname"];
NSData * data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[self allData]]; // Get my array which I need to share
[appGroupData setObject:data forKey:@"Data"];
[appGroupData synchronize];
```

4) You may get object in extension:

```
NSUserDefaults * appGroupData = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.appname"];
NSData * data = [appGroupData dataForKey:@"Data"];
NSArray * arrReceivedData = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Comment: Unable to place code in 'Source code tag', thats why answer is not display in proper format

Answer (score 0):

You should use NSUserDefaults like this following and make sure 
you must have enabled app group in your provisional profile and app group must configure as a green symbol and it should add to your provisional profile & BundleID.

```
NSUserDefaults *sharedUserDefault = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.yougroup"];
[sharedUserDefault setObject:object forKey:@"yourkey"];
[sharedUserDefault synchronize];

NSUserDefaults *sharedUserDefault = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.yougroup"];
sharedUserDefault value = [sharedUserDefault valueForKey:@"yourkey"];
```