# How can I pass data view controller to extension

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, nsuserdefaults

How can I pass variable on VC to extensionVC when click to button? I try user defaults but it didn't work. And I try something like that but this also didn't work.

VC:

```
let appGroupDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName:"group.com.ReelKapi")!
    appGroupDefaults.set(secilenKapi, forKey: "secilenKapi")
```

Today Extension:

```
appGroupDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName:"group.com.ReelKapi")!
    var gelenKapi = appGroupDefaults.value(forKey: "secilenKapi")! as? String
    if let yansiyan = gelenKapi {

        gelenKapi = yansiyan
    }
```

Comment: Search for "App Groups". A feature to share a directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check this tutorial(BLOCK), i thinks its resolve your problem.](https://tapadoo.com/2014/sharing-nsuserdefaults-between-your-app-and-a-today-extension-on-ios-8/)

- **Duplicate [Cannot access NSUserDefaults using app groups one to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33834002/cannot-access-nsuserdefaults-using-app-groups-one-to-another)**

Answer (score 1):

1st you have to create and enable App groups.

And then,

Do synchronise your defaults values.

VC:

`let appGroupDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName:"group.com.ReelKapi")!
appGroupDefaults.set(secilenKapi, forKey: "secilenKapi")
appGroupDefaults.synchronize()`

Synchronize UserDefaults after you set.

Today Extension:

`appGroupDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName:"group.com.ReelKapi")!
appGroupDefaults.synchronize()`

`var gelenKapi = appGroupDefaults.value(forKey: "secilenKapi")! as? String
if let yansiyan = gelenKapi {
  gelenKapi = yansiyan
}`

Synchronize UserDefaults before you access the value.