# How can I share data between the container macOS app and my Xcode Source Editor Extension?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, macos, osx-extensions

I have made an Xcode Source Editor extension, and it lives within a container app, as Apple recommends. The container app handles the UI, and accordingly the input from the user that needs to be set for my extension to work right.

How can I take the input I get in the container app and make it available to the extension to access when it needs it? I tried using NSUserDefaults but it didn't work as I hoped.

Comment: Whay the `NSUserDefaults` approach didn't work exactly ? It should work if setup properly.

Comment: I don't know, the value was set in the main app and then nil when I tried pulling it out in the extension. What other setup is required?

Comment: Take a look at this post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118918/sharing-data-between-an-ios-8-share-extension-and-main-app.