# Swift 3 - Share URL and title from share extension to main app?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, share-extension

I've got the following from [this tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-build-an-ios-share-extension-in-swift-4a2019935b2e) on creating a ShareExtension:

```
override func didSelectPost() {
        self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Which uses this javascript to get the url:

```
var GetURL = function() {};
GetURL.prototype = {
   run: function(arguments) {
      arguments.completionFunction({"URL": document.URL});
   }
};
var ExtensionPreprocessingJS = new GetURL;
```

I'd like to understand how I can modify the the `didSelectPost` so I can pass this URL to my main app. I've created a shared app group from [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31927904/7768174), but the problem is my main app uses Firebase to store and update the TableView (which is just a list of URLs, like a reading list). I understand I can't use Firebase in the shareExtension (they are meant to be as simple as possible) - but I can't figure out a way of doing it otherwise.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -3):

Create a variable: `var url: URL?` on the top of your ShareViewController. Then, add this code in the viewDidLoad to set the value of your url:

[image: viewDidLoad Code]

You can then try to access the url variable in your didSelectPost area through a guard statement: `guard let successfulURL = self.url else { return }`, and use the successfulURL variable however you would like to. Hope this helped.