# NSUserDefaults with SuiteName works on simulator but it doesn't on the device

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, ios8

I really don't know how to approach this.
I'm creating a keyboard extension and I need to share some data between my application and my plugin. I'm trying to use NSUserDefaults.

I have the following snippet in my application

```
userDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.____"];
[userDefaults setObject:@"w/e" forKey:@"mykey"]; //in my app
[userDefaults stringForKey:@"mykey"]; //in my extension
```

I have created the group ID in itunes connect, updated the application ID for both the app and the extension, I have recreated the provisioning profile and I have add the following entitlements

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
        <array>
            <string>group.com.___</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

everything works great... on the simulator. when I access `myKey` running the plugin from the device I get a nil object back.

not that, the object `userDefaults` it self is not nil.

any help?

**EDIT**
the problem doesn't seem to show up if I ask and grand full-access to the plugin. but why would I need full-access to use this functionality? and why do I need it on the device and not on the simulator?

Comment: I'm testing it on beta5

Comment: I think after setting the object you are not synchronising it.

Write [userDefaults synchronize]; after setting object

Comment: yes I am. I have paste the code that does it, but I am. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Are the identifiers matching in your actual code? Listed here they are not equal : `...SuitName:@"group.com.____` vs `...<string>group.com.___`. I assume just a typo here since you report it works in the simulator alright.

Comment: @Luka do you get any message to the console when you run the app on a device ? since it is working when you give full-access I would search for any sandbox violation message.

Comment: @Luka it seems that this is an open issue which is not fixed yet. I just did some research and you are not the only one who has the problem to make it works on a device: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24015506/communicating-and-persisting-data-between-apps-with-app-groups/24063144#24063144 
 OR 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/24296373/977094

Comment: Is it occurring on iOS8 only? or have you tried it on 7 or below?

Comment: there are not extensions in iOS7. this is an iOS8-only application.

Comment: Hi @Luka you talk about a "grand full-access" but what are you talking about ? I'm really interested about your solution ! Thks !

Comment: Hey @Luka have you solved your problem? I am experiencing the same issue.