# Is it possible for extensions access the containing-app's container directory?

Tags: ios8, ios-app-extension

Is it possible for extensions access the containing-app's container directory?

For iOS5-based app, i don't want to move all my old data into shared-contatiner, i wish that main-app can remain the same, and the extension just read & write the old data directly, that will be perfect!~

Comment: possible duplicate of [Communicating and persisting data between apps with App Groups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24015506/communicating-and-persisting-data-between-apps-with-app-groups)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24028248/2446155

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your widget may never access the containing app's data directly, only if the containing app puts that data into a shared container using app groups. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW6) (including the [WWDC videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/)) is pretty clear about this.

There's a high chance that your iOS-5-based app needs major changes anyway to work nicely on iOS 8.

Comment: Thanks, it sounds a huge project to move the data considering a lot of user and some update action.