# iOS launch app inside app

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

I am developing two apps and I want to access from one app to another.

My idea is to work in the app A, and when I click a button, open app B, select a photo of this app and go back again to app A.
The behavior that I want to reproduce is quite similar to the behavior of the photo camera.

How can I do that? I have tried using:     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]];

but with this function I lose the control of the app, I cannot go back with the image or I don't know how to do it

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can open App B using a custom URL scheme (as you are currently doing):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURLForAppB]];
```

Select the image and save it to the pasteboard (or you could upload to a server, but that is more complicated, time consuming, data intensive...):

```
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setImage:myImage];
```

Open App A again using another custom URL scheme:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURLForAppA]];
```

Extract the image from the pasteboard:

```
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
UIImage *myImage = pasteboard.image;
```

Comment: Never hijack the users pasteboard - users can have valuable data in there! Instead use some kind of scheme to transfer. In iOS 8 there are app groups that allows different apps to have access to the same containers. Way better solution! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24387871/share-datas-between-two-apps-with-ios-8-app-groups-using-nsuserdefaults http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24015506/communicating-and-persisting-data-between-apps-with-app-groups/24063144#24063144