# Share data between targets in xcode project

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a project with two different targets (a free and a paid version of the same app) and I have a `list` with items that I save to `NSUserDefaults`. My question is, is there any way to share this list between the two version of the app, without using `KeyChain` or something similar ?

Comment: Using app groups  it will be possible to share files or database. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24387871/share-datas-between-two-apps-with-ios-8-app-groups-using-nsuserdefaults

Comment: this is a hacking question....seems to be you are doing some free work for paid versions...

Comment: @GhanshyamTomar no, the idea is, that the user may use the free version for a while and then move to the paid one. I want to be able to import his saved items from the free app.

Comment: @Leena gave you good suggestion and i think there is way to make a list item to file like json or db somethings and export to external folder...and then get it when you want from there...

Comment: IT IS NOT DUPLICATED QUESTION. Sharing data between targets is not the same as sharing data between apps. One app can have a few targets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your can use App Group and save items in it.
***Project*** -> ***Capabilities*** -> ***App Groups***

1. Add App Group in your targets
2. Using `NSUserDefaults`

ex:

```
NSUserDefaults *myDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"com.group.identifier"];
```