# Share **file** between targets with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have an action extension and its accompanying app. In my action extension, files are **created**, and I want to be able to access them from my main app.

Using UserDefaults is not an option because I have to share relatively big files (including images, videos, etc.).

How can I achieve this?

[Not helpful.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39447153/xcode-sharing-files-between-targets) [Also not helpful.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30638929/share-data-between-targets-in-xcode-project)

Comment: Use a Shared Container to share data:  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html

Comment: @DavidShaw, it says there, though, that user defaults can be shared; there is no mention or implication of sharing files as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you do this is with an App Group.  As you saw, you can share using `UserDefaults`, but you can also share using the `FileManager`.

1. Create App Group under Targets->Capabilities:

[image: App Group Enable]

2. Access the directory via `FileManager`:

   ```
   fileprivate func sharedContainerURL() -> URL? {
       let groupURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.dsdevelop.appgroup")
       return groupURL
   }

   func writeSharedData(data:Data, to fileNamed:String) -> Bool {

       guard let url = sharedContainerURL() else {
           return false
       }

       let filePath = url.appendingPathComponent(fileNamed)

       do {
           try data.write(to: filePath)
           return true
       } catch {
           print("Write failed: \(error)")
           return false
       }
   }
   ```