# Access Notification Center / Today view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-privateapi

The aim is to read some values from a today widget (owned by Apple). Yes, using private API's is against Apple's guidelines but I'm just testing a thing.

Answer (score 0):

For realtime communication between widget and main app you can use [MMWormHole](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole).

For sharing data you can use [shared NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24390945/5479839).

Comment: The widget is owned by Apple, I'm trying to read it's values from my app

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed that. Unfortunately I can't help you with that :/

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is not possible. Accessing values from a Today widget from Apple would be the same from accessing values from a full app made by Apple. Which is simply impossible.

Otherwise you could access any values from any app at any point in time. That would cause a lot of security issues.

Even if it is one simple value you want to access, the premise is the same.