# Migration of App data to New IOS App

Tags: ios, app-data

Based on the current IOS app, my company planned to split it into two apps. Very likely, one of them will use the old App ID and the other one use a new APP ID.

We propose the app data to be transferred from the old app to the new apps with the process invisible to users.  The users are only required to update the old app to the latest version and install the new app.  The app data includes Core data, Keychain data, data in NSUserDefaults, data in plist file and data files.

Could you tell me if our requirements can be fulfilled and please suggest how can it be achieved.

Comment: What _is_ your proposal for data migration? You've proposed a requirement not a solution.

Comment: You  should consider data migration through server.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar Thx for your suggestion, but it's unlikely to go through server as there are thousands of users.  Our server cannot stand for it.

Answer (score 0):

App Group can be an answer to your problem: it enables several applications from the same group to share container.

See this SO question: [Communicating and persisting data between apps with App Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24015506/communicating-and-persisting-data-between-apps-with-app-groups)