# How to convert an array of custom classes to Data?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to convert an array of custom Note() classes to Data() to encrypt it later on and store it.

My class is

```
class Note: NSObject {
    var text = "hi"
    var date = Date()
}
```

The class above is an example. My class would be a bit more complex.

I've tried

```
let plistData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: mergedNotes)

if let a: Array<Note> = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: plistData) as? Array<Note> {
    print(a)
}
```

The above code crashes with a signal sigabrt.

How does this work and is it possible without encoding an decoding the entire class?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55820193/how-to-set-response-data-into-todayextenstion-widget/55820232#55820232 may help

Comment: It's needed to be `NSCoding` compliant to use `NS(Un)KeyedArchiver`. But you can use JSON, Plist, or anyother transformation, but need a converter (either the needed method of NSCoding, Codable, etc.)

Comment: It does crash, sorry for not beeing clear

Comment: Comment updated

Comment: Lot more detail needed. Do you want to store it in memory? Or persistent on disk?

Comment: @Larme I do have a convertor to JSON but its ugly so I wanted to know if I could do it withsome simpler code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all setup your Note class, must conform to the codable protocol:

```
class Note: Codable {
   var text = "hi"
   var date = Date()

   init(t: String, d: Date) {
      text = t
      date = d
   }

   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case text
      case date
   }

   required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
      let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

      text = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .text)
      date = try container.decode(Date.self, forKey: .date)
   }

   func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
      var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

      try container.encode(text, forKey: .text)
      try container.encode(date, forKey: .date)
   }
}
```

Then you can create your array of notes:

```
let arrayOfNotes: [Note] = [Note(t: "someNote", d: Date())]
```

And just save it in user defaults:

```
do {
    let encoded = try JSONEncoder().encode(arrayOfNotes)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "SavedNotes")
} catch let error {
    // catch any error if present
    print(error)
}
```

to retrive your saved data you can simply use an if let or a do-catch like above:

```
if let savedData = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "SavedNotes") as? Data {
   if let notes = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Note.self, from: savedData) {
    // do whatever you need
   }
}
```