# SwiftUI Core Data isn't able to fetch on WatchOS Target

Tags: ios, core-data, swiftui

I have the problem that my fetch request doesn't seem to work on WatchOS.

I enabled the "Watch APPNAME Extension" on my Database model but I still get that error (runtime) in my WatchOS ContentView.swift: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

My code:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(entity: Code.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var codes: FetchedResults<Code>

    var body: some View {
        Text("#\(self.codes.count)") <-- Error occurs here :(
    }
}
```

I'm pretty new to swift so I followed a tutorial by [hackingwithswift.com](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/how-to-combine-core-data-and-swiftui).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45607903/sharing-userdefaults-between-extensions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40065655/shared-userdefaults-between-app-and-extension-not-working-correctly

Comment: Did you solve this?  Seeing exact same issue.