# Share Data between Project and Share Extension

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, ios8-share-extension

I would like to share data between my `Main Project` and my `Share Extension`. This is what I did:

**1.** enable App Groups in both `Project` & `Share Extension`

**2.** save data in `Project` inside `viewDidLoad` (works fine, I tested it):

```
DataHandler.getWishlists { (success, dataArray, dropOptionsArray)  in
        if success && dataArray != nil {
            self.shouldAnimateCells = true
            self.dataSourceArray = dataArray as! [Wishlist]
            self.theCollectionView.isHidden = false
            self.theCollectionView.reloadData()
            self.dropOptions = dropOptionsArray as! [DropDownOption]
            self.addButton.isEnabled = true
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

            // save dataSourceArray in UserDefaults
            if let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: UserDefaults.Keys.groupKey) {
                defaults.setDataSourceArray(data: dataArray as! [Wishlist])
                defaults.synchronize()
            } else {
                print("error Main")
            }
        }
    }
```

**3.** retrive data in `Share Extension` (**`error 2` fires**!)

```
if let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: UserDefaults.Keys.groupKey) {
        if let data = defaults.getDataSourceArray() {
            dataSourceArray = data
            defaults.synchronize()
        }else {
            print("error 2")
        }

    } else {
        print("error 1")
    }
```

**UserDefaults + Helpers**

```
extension UserDefaults {

public struct Keys {
    public static let groupKey = "group.wishlists-app.wishlists"

    public static let dataSourceKey = "dataSourceKey"
}



func setDataSourceArray(data: [Wishlist]){
    set(try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(data), forKey: Keys.dataSourceKey)
    synchronize()
}

func getDataSourceArray() -> [Wishlist]? {
    if let data = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: Keys.dataSourceKey) as? Data {
        if let dataSourceArray = try? PropertyListDecoder().decode(Array<Wishlist>.self, from: data) as [Wishlist] {
            return dataSourceArray
        }
    }
    return nil
}
}
```

I can  not retrieve the data inside my `Share Extension` but I have no idea why. Could anyone help me out here?

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: It prints „error 2“ ( Point 3. in question)

Comment: can you get it back after a restart in the main app?

Comment: @Daij-Djan what do you mean exaclty? I tried `getDataSourceArray()` inside the main app and it works perfectly fine

Comment: in your `getDataSourceArray()` check if data is nil or you are getting some data ?

Comment: @jawadAli I get nil, but only when calling it inside the share extension. When I call `getDataSourceArray()` inside the Main App, I get the expected data

Comment: that means your extension is not getting data ... its not issue of decoding ... right

Comment: App Groups in both Project & Share Extension are sync ? Referring to same group ?

Comment: are your configuration same as this link ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40068298/1780632

Comment: @jawadAli I dont `set` the data inside the `App-Delegate` but this shouldnt make a difference right ?

Comment: no ... as far as your set code is executing .. its not an issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213048/discussion-between-chris-and-jawadali).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your helper function `getDataSourceArray()` tries to access `UserDefaults.standard` which is not shared between your host app and the extension app. You need to use the shared container.

- `UserDefaults.standard` -> **not** shared between host and extension
- `UserDefaults(suiteName:)` -> shared between host and extension

Try to change your function to this:

```
func getDataSourceArray() - > [Wishlist] ? {
    if let data = UserDefaults(suiteName: UserDefaults.Keys.groupKey).value(forKey: Keys.dataSourceKey) as ? Data {
        if let dataSourceArray =
            try ? PropertyListDecoder().decode(Array < Wishlist > .self, from: data) as[Wishlist] {
                return dataSourceArray
            }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: sorry not quite followimg you here. `UserDefaults + Helpers`  has both the Project and Extension as Target

Comment: Yes, but that only allows you to access the helper function from both targets. The helper function itself is accessing `UserDefaults.standard` which is not the shared container you created.