# Can we access App1's NSUserDefaults from App2?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsuserdefaults

I have two apps: App1 and App2.

In App1 I saved a key `tokenvalue` to `NSUserDefaults`.

I need to get the same `tokenvalue` in App2 as I got in App1. Is there any possiblity to get that value other than by using keychains?

Comment: Check below link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24015506/communicating-and-persisting-data-between-apps-with-app-groups?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: yes, you can, that is not an issue.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use ***App Groups***. This will let both apps save to a shared NSUserDefaults and File folder.

In Xcode, click on your project folder *Project Name* -> *DesiredTarget* -> *Capabilities* -> *App Group*, turn it on and create an associated app group.

Do this procedure for both App1 and App2.

from the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html

```
// Create and share access to an NSUserDefaults object
NSUserDefaults *mySharedDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName: @"com.example.domain.MyShareExtension"];

// Use the shared user defaults object to update the user's account
[mySharedDefaults setObject:theAccountName forKey:@"lastAccountName"];
```

Answer (score 3):

To store data:

```
var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.company.App")
userDefaults!.setObject("token123", forKey: "tokenvalue")
userDefaults!.synchronize()
```

To retrieve data:

```
var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.company.App")
if let tokenId = userDefaults?.objectForKey("tokenvalue") as? String {
  print("User Id: \(tokenId)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I'll check this.

Comment: Yeah Sure. If You Face any problem , then just tell