# iOS inter-process communication for real time data

Tags: ios, swift, ipc

Suppose we have 2 apps on iOS phone. What can we do to let one app send real-time data to the other one? Is there any best practice? Is it against security? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AppGroups](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW6) to achieve this. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24015506/communicating-and-persisting-data-between-apps-with-app-groups) question.

Comment: It requires extension. What if the two apps are not from one developer, like a middleware sending data to any third-party apps that are interested in the data?

Comment: Continuing C Luo's comment,  .... or a driver from a manufacturer to add support for their device to your app? Such as a Bluetooth Health Device (95% of which are proprietary).