# iOS InApp Purchase in Action Extension app

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, in-app-purchase, ios8-extension

I've tried to add a working inApp purchase view inside an Action Extension.

As you know, in Action Extension we have 2 targets, one is the normal App (the app you can download from app store), and the second one the extension.

The view inApp purchase, works in the normal app (first target) but doesn't work in the extension target, I mean the loading purchase product is loop running without found the purchase product.
I've also opened API for the extension target (no restricted API) on building setting.
Any one know how to do?

Comment: Please, click on "close" without a comment is inappropriate

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it in different way !
instead of trying to use in-App purchase on Action Extension itself
make the app checking on `UserDefault` with AppGroup !
.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24015506/communicating-and-persisting-data-between-apps-with-app-groups) will help you on how to share `UserDefault` with App Extension by using it with AppGroup

That mean the user **Must** use the app first
then when the user make the purchased , you will change value from `false` to `true` 
and save it to `UserDefault`

then when the user using the Action Extension
you will check the `UserDefault` 
if the value changed to `true`
then the user can use the Action Extension

**BTW** : I remembered reading about Apple will rejected the app if the App Extension didn't do any functions !
So I think you need to add some limitation if the user didn't purchased 
and remove the limitation after purchased

I hope this help you

Comment: Thank you for replay! But my intention is to have the Extension free and, if the customer like it, push donate button to donate something. If I've understood well your answer is not possible in my case.