# Disable popup when work with Shared Web Credentials (work directly)

Tags: objective-c, swift, security

Is there any way to work with data in shared web credentials directly, like with keychain, without showing popups on `SecAddSharedWebCredential` and `SecRequestSharedWebCredential`?

Or are there any other methods to work with it?

I want to share some data (string) between apps with different development teams.

Comment: Do you want to send data from App1 (Developer 1) to App2 (Developer 2) without Web API or Safari only using the iOS keychain?

Comment: I want to do that without additional user actions or opening app2 from app1 applications. I know that it's possible – Instagram does this somehow when you authorize with facebook there. But it uses an internet connection: it doesn't work without it.

Comment: Yes, is possible without internet connection using the Keychain functionality. Let me try an example.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to use the [KeychainAccess](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess) which is a simple swift wrapper. And using Keychain is the best way to store small pieces of data that are critical to your app, like secrets and passwords.

Also the tutorial from [raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/9240-keychain-services-api-tutorial-for-passwords-in-swift) would help you use the Keychain Services API.

Comment: Keychain can work only within one team, but I need to share data between apps in different teams

Answer (score 0):

App groups can be an option for your use case. Read below the apple API documentation and medium post

**App Groups**
Use a shared app group to share data/files between two/more apps or containing apps. An app group creates a secure container that multiple processes can access. Normally, each process runs in its own sandbox environment, but an app group lets both processes share a common directory.

Apple API docs - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_application-groups

https://medium.com/@dinesh.kachhot/different-ways-to-share-data-between-apps-de75a0a46d4a

Also here is another stackoverflow post answering similar question - [Communicating and persisting data between apps with App Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24015506/communicating-and-persisting-data-between-apps-with-app-groups)

Comment: I cannot add two apps from different teams in one group. Xcode says, that I cannot take this group name when I try to add the second app in existing group