# What is "big" for keychain?

Tags: ios, keychain

When storing a binary blob of data in keychain for security reasons, what is considered a "big" blob of data?  1kB?  1MB?  How big a blob of binary data can you store in keychain (without running into performance issues and whatnot).

Comment: Please refer to 
[Maximum keychain size][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488793/is-there-any-length-limit-of-string-stored-in-keychain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum length of your keychain string can be somewhere between **4 to 4.5 billion** characters. You most likely aren't going to need to worry about this.

Comment: Where did you get the 4Gig number from?  Empirical testing shows the value to be much less (in the 16Meg range.)