# Save file in ios that retain even the app is deleted - Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I would like to save a file programmatically and fetch it. Is it possible to create a file and save it locally and retain it even the app is deleted?

Comment: You cant, if the data is small enough Keychain is ur best bet to retain the data across installations

Comment: @SandeepBhandari If I just gonna store a String, what is the limit of the keychain?

Comment: Hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488793/is-there-any-length-limit-of-string-stored-in-keychain

Answer (score 4):

No you can't do this, Because all files is depend on app container and when you uninstall app container automatically removed.

But for that you can use **iCloud** or **Dropbox** for file storage and after you can retrieve same file,

Answer (score 1):

You can use iCloud to sync user's data (such as a database). So when application is deleted and downloaded again, saved data in iCloud will be sync with app bundle on downloading process.